# What's equivalent to this Homebrew installation command

Tags: software-installation, diff

What's the equivalent command on Ubuntu to

```
brew install wdiff --with-gettext
```

on Mac OS X?

EDIT:

I'm trying to prepare a computer for somebody else to use.  His coworker usually use Mac where wdiff is installed using the above command.  I'd like to get as close as possible on this Linux computer I'm setting up for him as certain processes they use could depend on that wdiff behave accurately.  I don't really know what `--with-gettext` does or why they needed it.

Comment: When asking about commands from another OS, don't assume we know what they do. Please [edit] your question and explain exactly what the command does. That way, we will be able to offer an equivalent.

Answer (score 3):

[`gettext`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/) is a library for internationalization and localization. The `--with-gettext` flag makes `brew` configure and build `wdiff` with that library, enabling i18n and l10n. However, the `wdiff` package for Ubuntu is not built with it. If you do need i18n, you'll have to build `wdiff` yourself. If you don't need it, `sudo apt-get install wdiff` is sufficient.

Comment: How do I build it myself with that capability on Ubuntu? I.e. what's the answer to my original question?

Comment: @qazwsx how about a "thank you"? Your original question is very unclear, I asked you to explain and you just ignored me. Three people have tried to answer you and your only response is a sarcastic _yeah, so what's the answer to the question I haven't explained clearly_? That is really not the best way to get volunteers to help you.

Comment: Indeed.  I edited too quickly without etiquette and details.  Sorry, and many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the `--with-gettext` option, but `wdiff` is [in the repos](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/wdiff) and you can install it with

```
sudo apt-get install wdiff
```

Answer (score 0):

It is:

```
sudo apt-get install wdiff
```

Comment: So `--with-gettext` is equivalent to not having any particular options for `apt-get`?